# How to make a prompt that asks for data?

Tags: javascript, lua

Is there a prompt function that asks the user for data in Lua?

For example I know Java Script has the prompt() but does Lua?
Eg.

```
    name = Prompt("What is your Name?","Default Data to be inserted")
    print(name)
```

Comment: That entirely depends on your setup. Where is your Lua embedded?

Comment: A command line, Thanks to jpjacobs for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're simply using the command line interface, you could use this:

```
function prompt(question,def)
   io.write(question,'\n','[',def or '',']:')
   return io.read('*l'):match'^%s*(%S.*)%s*' or def
end

prompt("Enter your name.","John Doe")
prompt("Enter your name.") -- works without default too.
```

This prints the default though it is not editable, just there to notify that if nothing is entered, it'll be used as default. You can edit the way how this is laid out if you want.

It reads a line as input, and if there's a non-space character, it will return whatever the input was, stripped of any leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: Thanks, I used it in a command line and removed a bit of code. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for  something like

http://www.gammon.com.au/scripts/doc.php?lua=utils.inputbox

Comment: No, this seems like to much work to import extra data. but I'll keep that page in mind.